# Barplot multiple variables (R)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, bar-chart

I want to create a bar plot with multiple variables.

I have several variables: "Do you go to restaurant", "Do you go to grocery store ?" ... All the values are "yes" or "no". I want to create a barplot with x = "yes" and "no" and y = count, fill = all the variable.

But I don't understand how to do it, I search on the internet but my problem is due to my x.

I tried this :

```
consommation_apres <- teletravail %>% select(reponse = rep("yes","no"), AP_livraison,AP_livraison_plateforme,AP_aucun,AP_resto,AP_drive,AP_livraison)

ggplot(consommation_apres, aes(x = reponse, y = count(), fill = consommation_apres)) +
  labs(title="Consommation après le Télétravail") +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

This is my Data :

[Data in french oui = yes, non = no](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwsvE.png)

I really sorry for the question.

Thanks you for your help.

Comment: Can you share some of your data? You can enter `dput(teletravail)` into the console, then paste the result into your question. Or if it is a lot of data, then you can wrap the data in `head`, `dput(head(teletravail, 20))`

Comment: I added an answer with some sample data I made up. But please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15293191).

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the data into a long format for plotting if you are using `ggplot`. Here, we can also summarize the data before plotting.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "name", values_to = "response") %>%
  group_by(name, response) %>%
  summarise(cnt = n()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = response, y = cnt, fill = name)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  labs(title="Consommation après le Télétravail")
```

**Output**

[image]

Or if you wanted to see each category together, then we could do:

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "name", values_to = "response") %>%
  group_by(name, response) %>%
  summarise(cnt = n()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = cnt, fill = response)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  labs(title="Consommation après le Télétravail")
```

[image]

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(AP_livraison = c("yes", "no", "no", "yes", "no", 
"no", "yes", "no", "no"), AP_livraison_plateforme = c("yes", 
"yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "no"), AP_aucun = c("yes", 
"yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "no"), AP_resto = c("yes", 
"no", "no", "yes", "no", "no", "yes", "no", "no"), AP_drive = c("yes", 
"yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "no")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i million times thank you